# Method name not found for HtmlSelect

Tags: c#, selenium

I am writing tests for automated testing. I have declare element in my automated test like below

```
   [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Receiver_dropdown"), CacheLookup]
   private HtmlSelect _myReceiverDropdown;
```

Then i tried to send text like below

```
   this._myReceiverDropdown.SelectByText("XXX");
```

But i am getting **Method not found** error. This code used to work before but not sure why suddenly its not working.

Anyone has idea about this?

Comment: Which line causes that error? Is that the full error message? Can you share code that compiles?

Comment: @NicoHaase this line causes error  this._myReceiverDropdown.SelectByText("XXX"); Code is compiling with no problem

Comment: Are you sure that the code you've share compiles? Shouldn't there be a more concrete namespace for `HtmlSelect`? For example, the `HtmlSelect` within .NET does not contain the method `SelectByText`, which makes the error message pretty obvious

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selectbytext element not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367342/selectbytext-element-not-found)

Comment: `PageFactory` is no longer supported in `C#`